# Having trouble using .htaccess for hiding the .php extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble using .htaccess. 
This is the content of my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ $1 [L]
```

I opened up a text file, pasted these lines and saved it as .htaccess
It was showing .htaccess before i right clicked the .htaccess file and changed it to "open with notepad". I guess that shouldn't make a difference but now its showing a blank name.

The main problem is when i open my localhost on the browser through wamp, the folder where I've kept the .htaccess file, isn't visible or if i access it shows this internal server error.Now, if i remove the .htaccess file from there, it shows up in the localhost directory and doesn't show an error when i try to open it.

Comment: check if mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Okay,i enabled mod_rewrite and it has started showing the folder containing htaccess but i can still see .php extension

Comment: @Prateek What do you want your end users to see? Normally, the idea is that your user enters `example.com/somepage` and that is translated invisibly to `somepage.php`. The links on your site should be changed not to include the .php extension, and your users won't see them.

Comment: Oh. My bad i thought if i type in something like index.php it'll be shown as index, but i guess it works the other way round. It worked. Thanks a lot Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting the 500 Internal Server Error, your .htaccess file is being read. From what I see, you may be missing spaces before the `!`:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #-----------------------------^^
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #-----------------------------^^
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ $1 [L]
```

But if you want your users not to see the .php extension, the `RewriteRule` is backwards. The first part should not contain the .php:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
  # The input URL has no PHP, but internally is served as .php 
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Still wont show the folder where the htaccess file is placed and yes it shows the 500 internal server error. removed the space before the !. didnt work.